How can solve Target SWGI script '/aa/bb/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'?
When I change sqlite3 to postgresql, I receave error,
this error I have only then I run apache2,
if I start "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" its work fine.
I tried so many things, but I couldn't find the answer.
psycopg2 is installed.
Part of error:
file "/../...postgresql/base.py", line 25..
  import psycopg as Database 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module namged 'psycopg'

file "/../...postgresql/base.py", line 27..
  import psycopg2 as Database 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module namged 'psycopg2'
..
..
Traceback (..):
 file /../../wsgi.py
   application =get_wsgi_application()
..
..
..
..

mod_wsgi (pid-1111): Target SWGI script '/aa/bb/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'


remove libraries and renew install, restart apache2, correct wsgi.py, 000-default.conf

For the first part you can try installing psycopg2-binary using this command:
pip install psycopg2-binary

for the second part, it seems there is an issue with your wsgi.py file, may you provide more logs?

I have installed the psycopg2, also sometimes tried both libraries, but did not work.

I solved my problems, when I created new environment in my project, everything is ok.
Maybe, I had mistake in old environment when I tried install any libraries.
